# How to say Camel file route to wait for another file route that is slow?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, apache-camel-file

I have a route that moves files to the destination directory. The route works this way - it does preMove to the processing folder, and when all is okay, it moves the file to the .done directory.

If the route fails, I have a list of all files that should have been moved to the .done folder, but the Camel file route is slow in writing them. I am getting in the situation when the Camel file route is still writing files to a directory while I am moving it to another folder in another route in the processor.

What is the most Camel way to fix it?

I know files. I know directories files will be eventually written to.

**UPDATE 1:**
I have in my first file route these params:

`readLock=idempotent-changed&readLockMinAge=3s`

The question is, should I wait for 3s to make route trigger and then move files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [section](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#File2-Consumingfilesfromfolderswhereothersdropfilesdirectly)

> ... **The best approach is however to
> write to another folder and after the write move the file in the drop
> folder.** ... You **may also want to look at the
> doneFileName option**, which uses a marker file (done file) to signal
> when a file is done and ready to be consumed.

---

- Use `doneFileName` option

[Write a marker file](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_writing_done_files) in the producer route and [read data file](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_using_done_files) in consumer route when related marker file exist.